# Fomin et al., Mathematical Circles Chapter 4- Pigeon Hole Principle Problem 12. Max. no. of kings that can be placed so no two put each other in check

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, pigeonhole-principle, packing-problem, chessboard

I found this problem in Mathematical Circles in the Pigeon Hole Principle chapter:

> What is the largest number of kings which can be placed on a chessboard so that no two of them put each other in check?

I found the answer to be $16$, and was able to prove it is the maximal case. Here is the arrangement:

[image]

I think I've misunderstood, since the answer is $12$. The hint says to divide the chessboard into $2 \times2$ squares, which was how I proved $16$ is the maximal case. Maybe it is asking for an arrangement such that even if one king moves, he can not check the other?

Comment: You are correct, your book is wrong.

Comment: It could be a typo. If you divide the chessboard in $2\times 2$ squares there are 16 such squares and each square can contain at most one king, which proves by the pigeonhole principle that the maximum is at most 16.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation @Gribouillis